# Calculate the $[(1/2 \,0)^t; (1\,1/2)^t]^k$

Tags: matrices, discrete-mathematics

I have a matrix A as following:
$$ A =\left[
    \begin{array}{cc}
      \frac1 2 & 1\\
      0 & \frac1 2
    \end{array}
\right] $$

How to find $A^k$? If $k\to\infty $, what is the solution of $A^k$?
Based on some suggestion, I found $A^k$
$$ B_k =\left[
    \begin{array}{cc}
      1 & 2k \\
      0 & 1
    \end{array}
\right], $$
where $A_k=\frac 1 {2^k}B_k$

Comment: Can you diagonalize a matrix?

Comment: Not this one :)

Comment: "If $k\to\infty $, what is the solution of $A^k$?" This doesn't make much sense. Are you asking for $\lim \limits_{k\to \infty}\left(A^k\right)$? If so, then what is your definition of $\lim$ here? Since this is tagged (discrete-mathematics), I guess the definition of the limit is the matrix whose entries are the limits of the entries of $A^k$. With this definition, what's stopping you from finding the limit?

Answer (score 2):

$A$ has an obvious factor $1/2$, so let $A=B/2$, where 
$$B=\left[\begin{array}{cc}1&2\\0&1\end{array}\right]$$
Calculate $B^k$ for $k=2,3,4$, and deduce the general form of $B^k$.  Then $$A^k=\frac1{2^k}B^k$$

Comment: Check my update again. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Comment: How about if k goes to infinity? Sir

Comment: Do you know the limit of $2k/2^k$ as $k$ goes to infinity?

Comment: I think it go to 0, right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct

Answer (score 0):

Calculate $A^2$ and compare that to $A$. The pattern will then be clear and $A^k$ will be obvious, as well as its limit.